# Do the printf statements in this example invoke Undefined Behavior?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

Derived from *[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747225/p-is-a-pointer-to-a-structure-what-do-all-these-code-snippets-do/53747666#53747666)*...
Given the declaration in line 1 of `main`, are the second and third `printf` statements considered undefined behavior because they point to locations not owned by this process?

```
struct my_structure {
    int i;
};

void main() {
    struct my_structure variable = {20};
    struct my_structure *p = &variable;

    printf("NUMBER: %d\n", p++->i);  
    printf("NUMBER: %d\n", p++->i);   
    printf("NUMBER: %d\n", p++->i);   
}
```

Comment: the first one doesn't...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - Yes, got that.  Interested in your thoughts about 2nd and 3rd statements.

Comment: your answer in the link indicate that you already knew about that :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - Your comment (and now your answer) parallel my thoughts, but in the chat, at the bottom of the comments in that linked question, there is an alternative viewpoint.  We agreed it would be good to post as a stand alone question.

Comment: oh I see, and I edited in the meanwhile, telepathy I guess.

Comment: Arithmetic on out-of-bounds pointers is UB: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473573/why-is-out-of-bounds-pointer-arithmetic-undefined-behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, first `printf()` is OK per C11 6.5.6.8

```
printf("NUMBER: %d\n", p++->i);
```

---

2nd `p++` is *undefined behavior* (UB), [@Osiris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53748369/do-the-printf-statements-in-this-example-invoke-undefined-behavior/53748667?noredirect=1#comment94350198_53748667), as it attempts to form a pointer more than 1 past `struct my_structure variable`.

The rest of code is irrelevant.

```
//                     vvv
printf("NUMBER: %d\n", p++->i);
```

---

Detail:  the 2nd post-increment of `p` may occur prior to or may be deferred until after the attempted UB access (with the pre-increment `p`).  As the increment and access are UB, either one leads to UB.

Comment: by your phrase _attempts to_ ***form*** _a pointer_, do you mean _attempts to_ ***move*** _a pointer_?  And if so, is it illegal to change the location of where a pointer is pointing even if it does not access that location?

Comment: @ryyker It is the pointer arithmetic (`p++`) which invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @Osiris - Yes, I have seen this comment by you in other locations.  Will you please explain it further?.  Thanks.

Comment: @ryyker Adding an integer to a pointer leads to undefined behavior if the result is further than one past of the end of the array object. So the first `p++` is fine since the result is only one past of the end, while the second is illegal. It is stated in ISO/IEC 9899:2011 6.5.6.8, see [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A227%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C-27%2C816%2Cnull%5D).

Comment: @Osiris - Thank you for that detail.  I did not know that.  It seems worth posting an answer.  Although alluded to in other answers, the clarity of reason makes it relevant.

Answer (score 1):

`p` is made so it points to an element, which isn't different from an array of 1 element.

So accessing more than one consecutive element by incrementing `p` is *undefined behaviour*.

To be valid you'd need to point to 3 consecutive elements like:

```
struct my_structure variable[3];  // should be initialized too
```

To be complete, `p++` in itself isn't the issue (the pointer points to an invalid location, so what? it's like this after most pointer loops), it's the fact that we try to *read* from the memory when doing `p->i` on an invalid location which is the problem.

Comment: Thanks.  This looks pretty clear, and parallels what I thought, and expressed in the question this one is derived from. (linked at top)  However, there are other viewpoints that have been expressed as well.  I hope to get some additional discussion.

Comment: discussing undefined behaviour is an all-time classic in the C tag :)

Comment: Actually pointer arithmetic is only allowed to go up to one over the end of an array, otherwise the arithmetic itself is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Osiris yes, but since you do nothing with the pointer it should not crash or something. Invalid it is But you're right. I don't know how to/if I should change my answer to add this.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I agree that it would be unusual to crash, but it is undefined behavior according to the standard, and since the question is asking about it ...

Comment: I'll leave it as is. Chux answer explains that exactly.

Comment: Re: “`p` is made so it points to an element”: “Element” is not the correct term here. An element is a member of some collection. `p` is set to point to the single object `variable`, not to an element. `p` does behave, for pointer arithmetic, as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one.

Comment: It is not okay for this answer to assert that pointer arithmetic itself is not the issue. C permits implementations to have complicated pointer implementations, in which merely doing arithmetic on pointers may require accessing behind-the-scenes data, so doing invalid pointer arithmetic can crash.